# Loading reports in bowser using Web API c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a stored procedure to load a report as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  rptCheckListReport

@iCompanyId BIGINT,
@szITSfromPersol VARCHAR(100),
@szGroupBy varchar(10),
@szGroupBy1 varchar(10),
@szQuery1 VARCHAR(500),
@szQuery2 VARCHAR(500),
@szQuery3 VARCHAR(500),
@szQuery4 VARCHAR(500),
@szPicHeight VARCHAR(50),
@szPicWeight VARCHAR(50)

AS

BEGIN
    SELECT  
        distinct  i.szDescription AS InspectionName, UPPER((Select Top 1 c.szName From Criteria c Where c.pkID = m.iCriteriaId)) AS CriteriaName,
            m.nInpectionScore as InspectionMasterScore,cq.szQuestion AS CriteriaQuestion, cq.nMax AS CriteriaQuestionMax,
        (Select Top(1) szCompanyName From ADMIN.dbo.psAdCompany) AS CompanyName 
    FROM


psIMLInspectionMaster m 
        JOIN Inspection i ON m.iInspectionId = i.pkID
            JOIN CriteriaQuestion cq ON m.iCriteriaQuestionId = cq.pkID
            JOIN CriteriaQuestionGrading cqg ON m.iCriteriaQuestionGradingId = cqg.pkID
    WHERE   dInspectionDate between '' + ltrim(rtrim(@szQuery3)) + '' and '' + ltrim(rtrim(@szQuery4)) + '' + ltrim(rtrim(@szQuery1)) + '' + ltrim(rtrim(@szQuery2)) 
END
```

I have created a report file using Crystal Report.

I have created the following c# code that helps me load the report in the browser:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateCheckListReport(long lngCompanyId, string szITSfromPersol, string strGroupBy,  
        string strGroupBy1, string strQuery1, string strQuery2, string strQuery3,
        string strQuery4, string strPicHeight, string strPicWeight)
    {
        string Username = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"]);
        string Password = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
        string Servername = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DSN2"]);
        string Databasename = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["databasename"]);
        string type = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportType"]);

        if (strGroupBy.IsEmpty()) strGroupBy = "";
        if (strGroupBy1.IsEmpty()) strGroupBy1 = "";
        if (strQuery1.IsEmpty()) strQuery1 = "";
        if (strQuery2.IsEmpty()) strQuery2 = "";
        if (strQuery3.IsEmpty()) strQuery3 = "";
        if (strQuery4.IsEmpty()) strQuery4 = "";

        ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
        TableLogOnInfo crtablelogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables crTables;
        reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptCheckList.rpt"));
        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Servername;
        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Databasename;
        crConnectionInfo.UserID = Username;
        crConnectionInfo.Password = Password;
        crTables = reportdocument.Database.Tables;
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crTable in crTables)
        {
            crtablelogoninfo = crTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtablelogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtablelogoninfo);
        }

        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@iCompanyId", lngCompanyId);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szITSfromPersol", "Persol Systems Limited.");
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szGroupBy", strGroupBy);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szGroupBy1", strGroupBy1);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szQuery1", strQuery1);                                     // and #tblRetOutletSumm.iDistrictID=8
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szQuery2", strQuery2);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szQuery3", strQuery3);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szQuery4", strQuery4);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szPicHeight", strPicHeight);
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("@szPicWeight", strPicWeight);

        ReportExportType ReportExportType = Helper.Helper.GetReportExportType(type);

        reportdocument.ExportToDisk(ReportExportType.FormatType, Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptFiles/" + ReportExportType.ExportName));

        MoveImageFiles();

        return File(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/rptFiles/" + ReportExportType.ExportName), ReportExportType.ExportMimeType);
    }
```

The report is working fine but this is how i am calling the report in my browser:

```
****http://localhost:59139/home/CreateCheckListReport?lngCompanyId=1&szITSfromPersol=Persol&strGroupBy=Region&strGroupBy1=Inspection&strQuery1=&strQuery2=&strQuery3=2016-10-27&strQuery4=2016-10-27&strPicHeight=1&strPicWeight=1****
```

As you can see, I am passing all the parameters defined in my stored procedures here in the browser what shouldn't be the case.

I am now looking for a way to load my report file in a browser without passing the parameters in the browser.

I want that something below should load the report for  me:

**http://localhost:59139/home/CreateCheckListReport**

Any help would much appreciated.

Best Regards,

Somad

Comment: Make a private method which expects all these parameters and call it from your marked `webmethod`.

Comment: You can create a class encapsulating all the parameters as properties. And have the controller action as post. Post the class object to the controller action. Rest is same. This will not show the parameters in url but will go as post body. How exactly are you calling this action from client?